# Retrieving default currency for a company file using QBXML for QBD

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

I am trying to figure out the currency that is used for a QuickBooks file.

It seems that if a user is not using multi-currency feature there is no currency format associated with any transactions.

- I've tried: `HostQueryRq` which returns CountryCode but this seems as an optional return.
- `PreferencesQueryRq` contains home currency code ONLY if multi currency is used.

Is there any other ways for me to retrieve the currency that is associated with the QB file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HostQueryRq returns details about the version of QuickBooks, which MAY have a correlation to the currency used, does not guarantee the currency. When creating a new file, if you do not turn on multi currency, you are never asked what currency to use. You can make an assumption based on the country edition of QuickBooks being used; US = USD, CA = CAD, UK = GBP, and AU = AUD, but there is no guarantee that this will always be the case. I can create a company file using the US version of QuickBooks to track CAD amounts, as long as I always enter everything in CAD amounts.

Comment: That's what I was assuming too. It seems that there is no safe way to assume the currency so we'll have a drop-down to specify currency if one wasn't detected.